# How do you determine if someone is worthy the Beta badge?

Tags: support, beta, badges

I'm wondering why I have not received the Beta badge. I've looked at the list of Beta badge recipients and it appears that I have been more active then several others.

How do you determine if someone is worthy the Beta badge?

Answer (score 4):

You have to be an active user of the site during private beta. After the private beta ends, the badges are awarded.